# Determine normal vectors of unknown 3D surface using scattered points

Tags: matlab, 3d, data-visualization, curve-fitting, delaunay

I have a set of (topologically simple) `x,y,z` points. Associated with each one of them is a scalar (`s`). I would like to visualize the results.

How could I have the (unit) normal of each node determined and then scaled in accordance of `s`, or is there a way to get a spatially distributed surface plot (plotted parallel to the data points plane)?

This is a sample of 3D points:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

So, this is a 4-dimensional data.
You can visualize your data as a function of 3 variables (x, y & z). You can use colour to represent the 4th variable (s).
For example, you do the same by drawing a 'scatter' plot in MATLAB.
The picture here depicts the same:

the picture is taken from MathWorks website

[image: the picture is taken from MathWorks website]

You can visit this link & see your self. It's about visualizing a 4-D data :
[Visualizing 4-D data](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/visualizing-four-dimensional-data.html)

Comment: Yes, this would be "if all else fail", but not quite as good as having vectors at each node which length is proportional to the scalar s.

Answer (score 2):

If your surface is unknown, you can use `delaunay` to fit a surface on points using delaunay triangulation. Then you can find normal vectors using `vertexNormal`.

```
%% generating some sample data
n = 1000;
d = 6;
zscale = 1/3;
x = rand(n, 1)*d - d/2 ;
y = rand(n, 1)*d - d/2;
z = peaks(x, y)*zscale;
s = 5./(1+(x.^2+y.^2));

%% calculating normal vectors
T = delaunay(x,y); % triangulation connectivity matrix
TR = triangulation(T,x,y,z); % the triangulation connectivity
V = vertexNormal(TR); % normal vectors at triangle vertices
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

The code used to plot above figures:

```
figure, subplot 121
scatter3(x, y, z)
[xg, yg, zg] = peaks(linspace(-d/2, d/2, 50));
zg = zg*zscale;
mesh(xg, yg, zg)
hold on
scatter3(x, y, z, s*100, '.');
colormap jet
axis equal, xlim([-d/2 d/2]), ylim([-d/2 d/2])
copyobj(get(subplot(121),'Children'),subplot(122))
legend('unknown surface', 'scattered data')
axis equal, xlim([-d/2 d/2]), ylim([-d/2 d/2])

figure, subplot 121
hold on
trisurf(T, x, y, z, 'edgealpha', 0.1)
quiver3(x, y, z, ...
    V(:,1),V(:,2),V(:,3),2);
grid on
view(3)
axis equal, xlim([-d/2 d/2]), ylim([-d/2 d/2])
colormap jet
copyobj(get(subplot(121),'Children'),subplot(122))
legend('fitted surface', 'normal vectors')
axis equal, xlim([-d/2 d/2]), ylim([-d/2 d/2])

figure, subplot 121
scatter3(x, y, z, '.')
hold on
quiver3(x, y, z, ...
    V(:,1).*s,V(:,2).*s,V(:,3).*s,5);

view(3)
axis equal, xlim([-d/2 d/2]), ylim([-d/2 d/2])
copyobj(get(subplot(121),'Children'),subplot(122))
legend('scattered points', 'scaled normal vectors')
axis equal, xlim([-d/2 d/2]), ylim([-d/2 d/2])
```

Comment: Not quite, in your example z is a function of x and y. In my case x,y and z are independent. I can use T=delaunay(x,y,z), but when I visualize the results is is a complete mess (as not all my points are on a planar surface)

Comment: @user2260180 why don't you generate a simple dataset that has characteristics of your actual data. Edit your post and put both data and the code that creates the mess.