# Matlab convert patch values to vertex value

Tags: matlab, interpolation, patch

I have n (2|3|4) adjacent patches sharing a vertex. Each patch is characterized by its normal vector (ok not normalized) and a scalar.

I would like to determine at the common vertex a vector (direction and magnitude) representative of the ones at the adjoining patches.

Is there a simple/elegant way to perform this operation (averaging the normalized vectors and scalars) to get a vertex value?

Ultimately, I am prepping data for Paraview (vtk file).

Comment: This looks somehow related to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65299430/determine-normal-vectors-of-unknown-3d-surface-using-scattered-points/65305951#65305951). Didn't the answers to the other question work? Why not? What did you try to overcome those problems? What is your data?

Comment: Not really, For my other question, the delaunay triangularization was not successful, probably due to the curvature of the surface. In this case, I am not trying to build patches, I do have patches on curved surface, with each patch I have a scalar, I intend to ultimately use ParaView to visualize "deformation" that would be proportional to the averaged scalar value at vertices. Right now the scalar (and normal) are associated with the patch (or cell in Paraview parlance), and I want to transfer the info to the vertex (points in Paraview parlance).